# SQL: Get multiple line entries linked to one item?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

```
ID | ITEMID | STATUS | TYPE
1  | 123    | 5      | 1
2  | 123    | 4      | 2
3  | 123    | 5      | 3
4  | 125    | 3      | 1
5  | 125    | 5      | 3
```

Any item can have 0 to many entries in this table. I need a query that will tell me if an ITEM has all it's entries in either a state of 5 or 4. For example, in the above example, I would like to end up with the result:

```
ITEMID | REQUIREMENTS_MET
123    | TRUE    --> true because all statuses are either 5 or 4
125    | FALSE   --> false because it has a status of 3 and a status of 5. 
                     If the 3 was a 4 or 5, then this would be true
```

What would be even better is something like this:

```
ITEMID | MET_REQUIREMENTS | NOT_MET_REQUIREMENTS
123    | 3                | 0
125    | 1                | 1
```

Any idea how to write a query for that?

Comment: Missing: table definition, Postgres version. Can any column be NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast, short, simple:

```
SELECT itemid
      ,count(status = 4 OR status = 5 OR NULL) AS met_requirements
      ,count(status < 4 OR status > 5 OR NULL) AS not_met_requirements
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY itemid
ORDER  BY itemid;
```

Assuming all columns to be `integer NOT NULL`.

Builds on [basic boolean logic](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-logical.html):
`TRUE OR NULL`  yields `TRUE`
`FALSE OR NULL` yields  `NULL`

And NULL is not counted by `count()`.

[->SQLfiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ed17f/2)

Answer (score 0):

simple one:

```
select
    "ITEMID",
    case
        when min("STATUS") in (4, 5) and max("STATUS") in (4, 5) then 'True'
        else 'False'
    end as requirements_met
from table1
group by "ITEMID"
```

better one:

```
select
    "ITEMID",
    sum(case when "STATUS" in (4, 5) then 1 else 0 end) as MET_REQUIREMENTS,
    sum(case when "STATUS" in (4, 5) then 0 else 1 end) as NOT_MET_REQUIREMENTS
from table1
group by "ITEMID";
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1f0a7/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID FROM (SELECT ID, MIN(STATUS) AS MINSTATUS, MAX(STATUS) AS MAXSTATUS FROM TABLE_NAME AS a GROUP BY ID)
WHERE a.MINSTATUS >= 4 AND a.MAXSTATUS <= 5
```

Comment: You are right Aleks G, I only wanted to show a possibly approach with nested selects

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be

```
SELECT t1.itemid, NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                             FROM mytable t2
                             WHERE itemid=t1.itemid
                             AND status NOT IN (4, 5)) AS requirements_met
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY t1.itemid
```

**UPDATE:** for your updated requirement, you can have something like:

```
SELECT itemid,
       sum(CASE WHEN status IN (4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as met_requirements,
       sum(CASE WHEN status IN (4, 5) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as not_met_requirements
FROM mytable
GROUP BY itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH dom AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM items
        )
,       yes AS ( SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS good_count FROM items WHERE status IN (4,5) GROUP BY item_id
        )
,       no AS ( SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS bad_count FROM items WHERE status NOT IN (4,5) GROUP BY item_id
        )
SELECT d.item_id
        , COALESCE(y.good_count,0) AS good_count
        , COALESCE(n.bad_count,0) AS bad_count
FROM dom d
LEFT JOIN yes y ON y.item_id = d.item_id
LEFT JOIN no n ON n.item_id = d.item_id
        ;
```

Can be done with an outer join, too:

```
WITH    yes AS ( SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS good_count FROM items WHERE status IN (4,5) GROUP BY item_id)
,       no AS ( SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS bad_count FROM items WHERE status NOT IN (4,5) GROUP BY item_id)
SELECT COALESCE(y.item_id, n.item_id) AS item_id
    , COALESCE(y.good_count,0) AS good_count
    , COALESCE(n.bad_count,0) AS bad_count
FROM yes y
FULL JOIN no n ON n.item_id = y.item_id
    ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, it was actually easy to do:

```
select  ITEM_ID , 
  sum (case when STATUS >= 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as met_requirements, 
  sum (case when STATUS < 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as not_met_requirements
from TABLE as d
group by ITEM_ID
```